# Snakemake - Tibanna config support

Tags: snakemake

I trying to run `snakemake --tibanna` to deploy Snakemake on AWS using the "Unicorn" Step Functions Tibanna creates.

I can't seem to find a way to change the different arguments Tibanna accepts like which subnet, AZ or Security Group will be used for the actual EC2 instance deployed.

Argument example (when running Tibanna without Snakemake):
https://github.com/4dn-dcic/tibanna/blob/master/test_json/unicorn/shelltest4.json#L32

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you noticed this option?

> snakemake  --help
>
> --tibanna-config TIBANNA_CONFIG [TIBANNA_CONFIG ...]
>                           Additional tibanan config e.g. --tibanna-config
>                           spot_instance=true subnet= security
>                           group=

I think it was added recently.

-jk