# snakemake/tibanna - defining ec2 instance config on per rule basses

Tags: amazon-web-services, snakemake

I am considering porting my pipeline to snakemake. I need to compute
loads of stuff on AWS.  Snakemake does this via tibanna.

Tasks executed by pipelines tend to be lumpy. Splitting fastq uses
a lot of disk but not much memory or cpu. Other tasks require   a lot of
memory. So, you want to be able to define multiple configurations of the AWS type and size of the associated disk.

On this related thread, Artiom Lichtenstein asks about how to config a AWS node.

[Snakemake - Tibanna config support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60618609/snakemake-tibanna-config-support)

This post show that the --tibanna-config can be used to define a
single configuration.

https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#TIBANNA

Is it possible to define this on a per rule basis?

*Update:* I was thinking of aws type as an explicit parameter to tibanna.   Is it possible it is derived from the rules resource section?

https://github.com/kern3020/snakemake/blob/master/snakemake/executors.py#L1903

-jk